# Unavailable add web module option

Tags: tomcat8

Add web module option is not available in the modules section in my tomcat server. how to resolve this?I tried installing different versions but still its the same.
So what can i do for this option to be enabled to configure the tomcat in my eclipse. so please help me with it?